# List of buyers for each product

Tags: query, plugins

I would like to know if it's possible to get the complete name of each buyers for a specific product or the orders list of a specific product ?

Answer (score 0):

Goto your wordpress phpmyadmin open database

1.All Woocommerce orders save in table-prefix_posts table

2.and Woocommerce order's meta info like :billing-addres,customer-name store in table-prefix_postmeta table

run SQL command in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table-prefix_postmeta` 
WHERE  `post_id` = any order-id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

you get list of product meta info.

```
_order_items
```

this meta-key store all product info which your customer order

**Logic**:

1.Retrieve all meta info in [WordPress Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)([WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)).

2.check if your required product id in  `_order_items`.if it is their, then print your customer name `_billing_first_name` or other info.

**Important Link:**

[WordPress Database Description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)

[Get Post Meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the query but I don't see any '_order_items' meta key.

Comment: did you replace the table-prefix in my query with your table-prefix

Comment: Of course I did, it returns a list of many meta info but I don't have this meta key

Answer (score -2):

to aguidis

```
select * from table-prefix_postmeta
where post_id='[order_id]'
```

you can get order's info :)